# Insert new middleware at the "right" location

Tags: c#, linked-list, extension-methods

I need to have my [logger middlewares](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/225454/logger-adapter-with-a-configurable-chain-of-responsibility-of-middlewares) (*nodes* of a linked-list) in the *right* order so that they complement each other and work as desired.

*Any* known middleware can be inserted anytime but the first and last. They will always be there. This means I'm always starting with two of them and the other ones will have to find their place somewhere inbetween.

#### API

I came up with the following algorithm. `middlewhere` is *some* current position. From there I *navigate* to the beginning, enumerate them and `Zip` another collection shifted by one. Then by using the `order` dictionary I check whether `insert` is after or equal `current` and before or equal `next` (in case multiple instances of the same middleware are used, they are *equal*). When I find the position, I call `InsertNext` and the work is done.

```
public static Middleware InsertRelative(this Middleware middleware, Middleware insert, IDictionary<Type, int> order)
{
    if (middleware.Previous is null && middleware.Next is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("There need to be at least two middlewares.");
    }
    var first = middleware.First();
    var zip = first.Enumerate(m => m.Next).Zip(first.Enumerate(m => m.Next).Skip(1), (current, next) => (current, next));

    foreach (var (current, next) in zip)
    {
        var canInsert =
            order[insert.GetType()] >= order[current.GetType()] &&
            order[insert.GetType()] <= order[next.GetType()];
        if (canInsert)
        {
            return current.InsertNext(insert);
        }
    }

    return default; // This should not never be reached.
}
```

#### Demo

Here's a working demo. I use three more helpers: `First`, `Last` and `Enumerate` to *navigate* the chain. The other classes are *dummies* that represent the types of middlewares from the other question or new ones that I've created since.

```
void Main()
{   
    var middlewareOrder = new[]
    {
        typeof(PropertySetter),
        typeof(Stopwatch),
        typeof(Attachment),
        typeof(Lambda),
        typeof(Scope),
        typeof(Serializer),
        typeof(Filter),
        typeof(Transaction),
        typeof(Echo),
    };

    var positions = middlewareOrder.Select((m, i) => (m, i)).ToDictionary(t => t.m, t => t.i);

    positions.Dump();

    // Default configuration.
    var middleware = new PropertySetter().InsertNext(new Echo());

    // Insert some new middlewares in an arbitrary order.
    middleware
        .InsertRelative(new Attachment(), positions)
        .InsertRelative(new Serializer(), positions)
        .InsertRelative(new Scope(), positions)
        .InsertRelative(new PropertySetter(), positions);

    // Show their order.
    middleware.First().Enumerate(m => m.Next).Select(m => m.GetType()).Dump();
}

public abstract class Middleware
{
    public Middleware Previous { get; private set; }

    public Middleware Next { get; private set; }

    public T InsertNext<T>(T next) where T : Middleware
    {
        (next.Previous, next.Next, Next) = (this, Next, next);
        return next;
    }
}

public static class LoggerMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static Middleware InsertRelative(this Middleware middleware, Middleware insert, IDictionary<Type, int> order)
    {
        if (middleware.Previous is null && middleware.Next is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("There need to be at least two middlewares.");
        }
        var first = middleware.First();
        var zip = first.Enumerate(m => m.Next).Zip(first.Enumerate(m => m.Next).Skip(1), (current, next) => (current, next));

        foreach (var (current, next) in zip)
        {
            var canInsert =
                order[insert.GetType()] >= order[current.GetType()] &&
                order[insert.GetType()] <= order[next.GetType()];
            if (canInsert)
            {
                return current.InsertNext(insert);
            }
        }

        return default;
    }

    public static Middleware First(this Middleware middleware)
    {
        return middleware.Enumerate(m => m.Previous).Last();
    }

    public static Middleware Last(this Middleware middleware)
    {
        return middleware.Enumerate(m => m.Next).Last();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Middleware> Enumerate(this Middleware middleware, Func<Middleware, Middleware> direction)
    {
        do
        {
            yield return middleware;
        } while (!((middleware = direction(middleware)) is null));
    }
}

public class PropertySetter : Middleware { }
public class Stopwatch : Middleware { }
public class Attachment : Middleware { }
public class Lambda : Middleware { }
public class Scope : Middleware { }
public class Serializer : Middleware { }
public class Filter : Middleware { }
public class Transaction : Middleware { }
public class Echo : Middleware { }
```

---

#### Questions

I don't think I'll be having hundreds of middlewares so this few helpers won't impact the performance terribly but maybe you can still think of anything more clever?

Comment: Would you ever need to change the order of types?

Comment: @dfhwze I highly doubt it but it is possible that a new non-built-in-type needs to be placed somewhere. Like when an application requires something specific in that domain but not general enough to be reused elsewhere.

Comment: Should middleware be able to get deactivated/activated, regardless of whether they are included in the chain? Or would you just remove them and insert them again? Perhaps it's just a one-time fixed setup at bootstrap.

Comment: @dfhwze this is an interesting question and a great idea... Some of them could definitely be switchable but I'll have to check whether this would work for all of them (especially with `Stopwatch` and `Scope` that currently relies on `Dispose`)

Comment: The ones that don't defer entries to the next in chain, could use a flag like that. Actually, the ones that defer, could also use that flag and just pass the entries when deactivated :)

Comment: @dfhwze I with I could accept your comment ;-]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Design Review

This pattern of using a comparison dictionary to configure the chain seems like a convoluted work-around for just creating the chain and being able to activate/deactivate certain middleware items in the chain.

Your input could be used as a factory instead.

```
var middleware = new PropertySetter(); // .. pick a root
middleware = middleware.InsertNext(new Stopwatch());
// and so on ..
return middleware.First();
```

You could then implement an `IsActive` flag. For instance, in your logging middleware (see referenced question):

> ```
> public abstract void Invoke(Log request);
> ```

You could change the pattern to:

```
protected abstract void InvokeCore(Log request);

public void Invoke(Log request)
{
    if (IsActive)
    {
        InvokeCore(request);
    }

    Next?.Invoke(request);
}
```

Also think about what to do when togling the `IsActive` flag. Some middleware might have local state that needs to be flushed to the next middleware in chain.

```
protected virtual void ActivateCore(bool active) {}

public bool IsActive
{
    get => active; // private field
    set 
    {
        if (active != value)
        {
            active = value;
            ActivateCore(value);
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Conventions

- `InsertRelative` returns `default` when unable to insert the middleware. I would throw an exception here.
- There is a general lack of argument checks against `null` in your public API.

Comment: Rewritten. Works like a charm! This was another silver-bullet ;-)

Comment: OT: once you hit 25k the green internet points are worthless because they don't give you any new privileges :-\

Comment: @t3chb0t Except for a long shot at the legendary badge ;-)

Comment: badges are borig, privileges are cool ;-] and there is only one badge that gives you the single-duplicate-vote priviledge. All others are just decoration hehe